# How can I pin a couple favorite contacts on the share sheet in iOS?

Tags: ios, sharing

Maybe this is not possible, but I would like to be able to pin a couple favorite contacts on the share sheet in iOS (17)

First, is this possible?

Second, how can I do it if it is?